# How to use Bazel's py_library imports argument

Tags: python, build, boto3, bazel

I'm trying to use Boto3 in a Bazel built project but can't seem to get the correct import for the library. Because of the Boto git repository, all the sources are in folders named `botocore` and `boto3` in the root of the repository. The imports are all `boto3.boto3`, with the first corresponding the name of the external dependency and second being the root folder in which the reside. How do I use the `imports` attribute of `py_binary` and `py_library` rules to import from the inner `boto3` instead of the other one?

This is what my workspace looks like:

`//WORKSPACE`

```
BOTOCORE_BUILD_FILE = """

py_library(
    name = "botocore",
    srcs = glob([ "botocore/**/*.py" ]),
    imports = [ "botocore" ],
    visibility = [ "//visibility:public" ],
)

"""

_BOTO3_BUILD_FILE = """

py_library(
    name = "boto3",
    srcs = glob([ "boto3/**/*.py" ]),
    imports = [ "boto3" ],
    deps = [ "@botocore//:botocore" ],
    visibility = [ "//visibility:public" ],
)

"""

new_git_repository(
    name = "botocore",
    commit = "cc3da098d06392c332a60427ff434aa51ba31699",
    remote = "https://github.com/boto/botocore.git",
    build_file_content = _BOTOCORE_BUILD_FILE,
)

new_git_repository(
    name = "boto3",
    commit = "8227503d7b1322b45052a16b197ac41fedd634e9", # 1.4.4
    remote = "https://github.com/boto/boto3.git",
    build_file_content = _BOTO3_BUILD_FILE,
)
```

`//BUILD`

```
py_binary(
    name = "example",
    srcs = [ "example.py" ],
    deps = [
        "@boto3//:boto3",
    ],
)
```

`//example.py`

```
import boto3

boto3.client('')
```

Checking for the contents of the build folder

```
$ ls bazel-bin/example.runfiles/*
bazel-bin/example.runfiles/__init__.py bazel-bin/example.runfiles/MANIFEST

bazel-bin/example.runfiles/boto3:
boto3  __init__.py

bazel-bin/example.runfiles/botocore:
botocore  __init__.py
```

When I try to run the example script I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'client'` I can `import boto3.boto3` but then using anything in it results in missing dependencies such as `boto3.sessions` because everything is nested in `<target-name>.boto3`

Comment: Does `from boto3 import boto3` work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're on the right track, but you're running into a subtle problem due to the ordering of the python sys.path.

If I run your example and print out sys.path in example.py, I see that the path contains in order:

```
bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/example.runfiles
bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/example.runfiles/boto3/boto3
bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/example.runfiles/boto3
```

The second line is due to the `imports = ['boto3']` in your WORKSPACE file.

I think you want the third line to be where you get `import boto3` from, because you want python to see `bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/example.runfiles/boto3/boto3/__init__.py`.

So when python evaluates `import boto3`, it sees `bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/example.runfiles/boto3/__init__.py`  from the first entry and uses that, instead of `bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/example.runfiles/boto3/boto3/__init__.py` from the third entry.

I think the answer here, is to name your "workspace" something other than the directory it contains. For example:

```
# WORKSPACE
new_git_repository(
  name = "boto3_archive",
  commit = "8227503d7b1322b45052a16b197ac41fedd634e9", # 1.4.4
  remote = "https://github.com/boto/boto3.git",
  build_file_content = _BOTO3_BUILD_FILE,
)

# BUILD
py_binary(
  name = "example",
  srcs = [ "example.py" ],
  deps = [
    "@boto3_archive//:boto3",
  ],
)
```

When I do this in your example, I get the following error: `ImportError: No module named dateutil.parser`, which I think is progress.

Answer (score 4):

### Files

```
$ tree
.
├── BUILD
├── WORKSPACE
├── requirements.txt
└── src
    └── main.py
```

### requirements.txt

```
$ cat requirements.txt 
boto3==1.13.4
```

### WORKSPACE

```
$ cat WORKSPACE 
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")
http_archive(
    name = "rules_python",
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/releases/download/0.0.2/rules_python-0.0.2.tar.gz",
    strip_prefix = "rules_python-0.0.2",
    sha256 = "b5668cde8bb6e3515057ef465a35ad712214962f0b3a314e551204266c7be90c",
)
load("@rules_python//python:repositories.bzl", "py_repositories")

py_repositories()

# Only needed if using the packaging rules.
load("@rules_python//python:pip.bzl", "pip_repositories")

pip_repositories()


# Python external packages installation
load(
    "@rules_python//python:pip.bzl", "pip3_import"
)

pip3_import(
    name = "lambda_deps",
    requirements = "//:requirements.txt", # Top level requirements.txt file
)

load("@lambda_deps//:requirements.bzl", "pip_install")
pip_install()
```

### BUILD

```
$ cat BUILD
load(
    "@lambda_deps//:requirements.bzl",
    "requirement"
)

py_binary(
    name = 's3_test',
    main = 'main.py',
    srcs = ['src/main.py'],
    deps = [
        requirement('boto3')
    ]
)
```

### src/main.py

```
$ cat src/main.py
import boto3


def hello_boto3():
    print('hello', boto3.client('s3'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello_boto3()
```

### Build and run

```
$ bazel clean && bazel build //:s3_test
Extracting Bazel installation...
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Starting clean (this may take a while). Consider using --async if the clean takes more than several minutes.
INFO: Analyzed target //:s3_test (24 packages loaded, 1234 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:s3_test up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/s3_test
INFO: Elapsed time: 11.666s, Critical Path: 0.25s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 5 total actions

$ ./bazel-bin/s3_test
hello <botocore.client.S3 object at 0x7ff1b6686b38>
```